# jq error syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>

Tags: syntax-error, jq

```
cat test.json | jq 'map(if ParameterKey == "Project"           then . + {"ParameterValue" = "jess-project"}             else .             end           )'

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
map(if ParameterKey == "Project"           then . + {"ParameterValue" = "jess-project"}             else .             end           )                                                                      
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: I get the same error with `Windows cmd shell quoting issues?` when attempting to run `jq 'map(if ParameterKey == "Project"           then . + {"ParameterValue" = "jess-project"}             else .             end           )'` in PowerShell, so I don't think it's a shell quoting issue.

Comment: Getting this issue in LINUX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object construction in `jq` uses syntax similar to JavaScript Object Notation (JSON).

`{"ParameterValue" = "jess-project"}` is not valid in JSON. Did you mean `{"ParameterValue": "jess-project"}`?

Comment: cat test.json | jq 'map(if ParameterKey == "Project"           then . + {"ParameterValue" : "jess-project"}             else .             end           )'
jq: error: ParameterKey/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
map(if ParameterKey == "Project"           then . + {"ParameterValue" : "jess-project"}             else .             end           )       
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: I would recommend that you read the manual at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/ to help you figure this out. Maybe you meant `.ParameterKey`?

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this after reading [this here](http://engineering.monsanto.com/2015/05/22/jq-change-json/), and thought I add these notes, even if original post was so long ago. Hope it helps someone.

Aside from the incorrect use of `=` instead of `:` as pointed out above, I was also making the wrong assumption about the entire JSON object. So, make sure you're parsing that `test.json` correctly. For instance, if all ParameterKey/ParameterValues are in a list called `Parameters` and it looks something like this:

```
$ cat test.json
{
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "ParameterKey": "Project",
      "ParameterValue": "jess-project"
    },
    {
      "ParameterKey": "NumberOfInstances",
      "ParameterValue": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you have to take into account the `Parameters` list by doing:

```
$ jq '.Parameters | map(if .ParameterKey == "Project" then . + {"ParameterValue":"my-project"} else . end) | {"Parameters":.}' test.json
{
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "ParameterKey": "Project",
      "ParameterValue": "my-project"
    },
    {
      "ParameterKey": "NumberOfInstances",
      "ParameterValue": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the list is added back at the end, by the last pipe.

By the way, here's another way to update a key's value:

```
$ jq '.Parameters | map((select(.ParameterKey == "Project") | .ParameterValue) |= "my-project") | {"Parameters":.}' test.json
{
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "ParameterKey": "Project",
      "ParameterValue": "my-project"
    },
    {
      "ParameterKey": "NumberOfInstances",
      "ParameterValue": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

And if you want to specify a shell variable, you can even do this:

```
PRJ=my-project
jq --arg prj "$PRJ" '.Parameters | map((select(.ParameterKey == "Project") | .ParameterValue) |= $prj) | {"Parameters":.}' test.json > test-updated.json
```

In above example we're redirecting the modifications to new file `test-updated.json`, because invariably you'll most likely want to do that anyway since `jq` just doesn't have a replace-in-place option like `sed -i`.